# Swift 3 allow label to be size of the text

Tags: swift

```
        postLocationLabel.sizeToFit()

        postUsernameLabel.font = UIFont (name: "HelveticaNeue-Thick", size: 11)
        postUsernameLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 25, y: 30, width: 85, height: 30)
        postUsernameLabel.textAlignment = .center
        postUsernameLabel.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 32/255, green: 113/255, blue: 165/255, alpha: 0.6).cgColor
        postUsernameLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
        postUsernameLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        postView.addSubview(postUsernameLabel)
```

This is the label I have and the value changes everytime a user presses on a different table cell so the text is sometimes longer, how do I make it so that it doesnt display the "...." at the end of a string. I tried using sizeToFit() before and after I declared the size and it just makes the label completley disappear

Comment: Looks like you're calling `sizeToFit()` on postLocationLabel, not postUsernameLabel? No need to call `sizeToFit()` before setting the frame; call it after that. And, make sure you call it when the text in the label changes. If this isn't helpful, perhaps post more of your code?

Answer (score 0):

You have some reading to do. Use [Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH7-SW1). Without knowing a lot more about the UI around your label, that’s about as specific as anyone can get but you’ll want to pay attention to “content hugging” when you read the documentation.